# Azure B2C Frontdoor fallback url

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup an Azure frontdoor for a custom domain of my Azure AD B2C tenant using the following instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow

This is all working fine, but I would like to add a redirect when somebody manually types the custom domain url, eg `login.mydomain.com`.

Now it lands on the same page as when you type my-tenant.b2clogin.com giving the following error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Instead of that error I would like that it redirects to my login url like `app.mydomain.com/authentication/login`.

Any idea how to acomplish this in the Azure Frontdoor config or Azure AD B2C config?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you found an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

So, turned out the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow) had some missing and misleading steps.
Here are they:

- In the 1st step of the documentation, you should make sure that you are adding the custom domain (e.g., `login.contoso.com`) not to the main tenant (where you have the subscription) but to the other B2C tenant where you want to replace the `yourtenantname.b2clogin.com` domain.
- In the 3rd step of the documentation, you are asked to add a CNAME record for the domain `login.contoso.com`, but you won't be able to do that, as you've added a TXT record on the first step.
  In this case, just feel free to remove the TXT record from the domain registrar (if you've successfully passed the validation of the first step) and then add the CNAME record (as mentioned in the third step).